# Parse.com Class Update From API

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a Parse Class called Currency that provides static exchange rates using the exact format from https://openexchangerates.org/. I do not need the rates "real time" so I would like to somehow GET the info using cloud code/scheduled job once a day and then overwrite the existing entry in Currency. When users query against the rates throughout the day, it uses the Parse class and not an API call to https://openexchangerates.org. Can overwriting a class or an object in the class be done in Parse.com? If not, are there suggestions on how to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your job and set it to run once a day as required. In the job, make the http request. Iterate the result received to process each conversion. For that conversion, run a query to find the existing item in the data store (if one exists) by matching the conversion currencies. Update this object or create a new one if no match was found.

An alternative would be to batch delete all conversions before processing the result. This isn't great though as it leaves a finite time when no conversions will be available to users and if there is an error not even an old conversion will be available.